# Convert XML using XSLT in R

Tags: xml, r, xslt

I have task currently being performed by SQL Server Reporting Services where it exports a dataset to an XML format using an XSLT that converts the typical schema to a bespoke one. In order to replace this report, I need to be able to similarly transform XML when the user wants to download it.

The end layout produced by XSLT is horrible - it involves padding and all sorts of whacky concatenations and I'd rather not reinvent the wheel by doing the whole transformation in the first conversion from data to XML.

My google-fu has failed me: how do I convert XML via an XSLT using R?

### MWE

Here is a script that uses iris data and converts it to XML (I use my package from CRAN purely to keep the code level down on the example). I then have [an XSLT (on gist)](https://gist.github.com/stephlocke/ddbf672443dd5b371457) that when I run the XML through in Visual Studio converts the XML but I don't know how to translate that activity into R.

```
library(optiRum)
library(XML)
irisdata<-convertToXML(iris)
saveXML(irisdata,"iris.xml")
```

Comment: can you execute a system call to run java? If so, download saxon9 PE and run that. I don't think there is a native XSLT2.0 library for R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for `Sxslt` package, just using example data

```
library("Sxslt")
library("XML")
files <- sapply(c("sqrt.xml", "sqrt.xsl"), function(f) system.file("examples", f, package = "Sxslt"))
```

Where `files[1]` is an xml file and `files[2]` is an xsl file

```
xmlParse(files[[1]])

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test>
  <sqrt>9</sqrt>
  <date/>
  <code>mean(rnorm(10000))</code>
</test>
```

Then use `Sxslt` to apply stylesheet

```
xsltApplyStyleSheet(files[1], files[2])
```

Gives

```
$doc
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<HTML>
  <body>
 sqrt: 3
 pow: 81
 date: Thu Jan 15 06:46:54 2015<i class="output">-0.0140224652198879</i>
  substring: an(rnor</body>
</HTML>


$stylesheet
An object of class "XSLStyleSheet"
Slot "ref":
<pointer: 0x108ef2a60>


$status
OK 
 0 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLInternalXSLTDocument"
```

### Extra guidance on installing Sxslt

- You will need to install `libxslt-dev` on your linux machine first
- The latest build no longer works with R 3.1.2, nor will it install from source further to [Bug #1](https://github.com/omegahat/Sxslt/issues/1) on it's repo. The kind raiser of the bug took a fork and fixed the package so you can use <strike>`devtools::install_github("cboettig/Sxslt")` to install it.</strike>

That version is no longer up, but you can use:

```
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("omegahat/Sxslt")
```

Comment: Will give it a go! looks like just the bit of kit I need

Comment: Aye - am just trying to install it, tisn't built for 3.1.2 so it's giving me some trouble

Comment: First tried doing it via the repo with devtools, similarly tried doing it from the tar file url. Gotta go and install some packages on the OS `fatal error: libxml/tree.h: No such file or directory`. I'll be back soon eventually with the full list of requirements for installing it.

Comment: Guidance added as suggested edit to answer for folks who might encounter similar troubles

Comment: Indeed: `install.packages("remotes");
remotes::install_github("omegahat/Sxslt")`  Too bad I cannot upvote twice.