# R: Delete HREF Attribute from HTML Doc

Tags: xml, r, xpath

Spent all afternoon trying to achieve what seems so incredibly simple.

I need to iterate through a number of webpages, removing the `href="..."` part of any anchor `<a>` tags so that when I turn these into PDF's to use as an online evaluation task they are no longer clickable.

The obvious approach to me was to load in the HTML file, parse it and then `gsub` out the href bit but using something like...

```
uri <- "myPage.html"    
doc.parsed  <- htmlTreeParse(uri, encoding = "UTF-8", useInternal=TRUE)    # parse HTML into tree structure
doc.anchors = unlist(xpathApply(doc.parsed, "//a"), xmlValue)
doc.anchors = gsub("href='([^\"]*)'", ' ', doc.anchors)
```

Just ends up as...

```
> doc.anchors
  [1] "<pointer: 0x109672dc0>" "<pointer: 0x109683560>" "<pointer: 0x109681a90>" "<pointer: 0x109623620>" "<pointer: 0x109621590>" "<pointer: 0x109621860>" "<pointer: 0x1096267b0>"
  [8] "<pointer: 0x109626ae0>" "<pointer: 0x109626e10>" "<pointer: 0x109627140>" "<pointer: 0x109627470>" "<pointer: 0x1096277a0>" "<pointer: 0x109627ad0>" "<pointer: 0x109627e00>"
 [15] "<pointer: 0x109628130>" "<pointer: 0x109628460>" "<pointer: 0x109628790>" "<pointer: 0x10962b1c0>" "<pointer: 0x10962b9b0>" "<pointer: 0x10962c660>" "<pointer: 0x10962cb70>"
 [22] "<pointer: 0x10962d080>"
```

Can anyone point me to something which will take an HTML document, find the anchor tags and just remove the href attribute (leaving the anchor tag in place)?

So `<a href="http://mytest.com/test.html"/>` would become just `<a/>`.

> UPDATE: Another hour on this and the following produces a nice list of the anchors stripped of the `href` attribute thusly...
>
> ```
> uri         <- "myPage.html" 
> doc.parsed  <- htmlTreeParse(uri, encoding = "UTF-8", useInternal=TRUE)    # parse HTML into tree structure
> doc.root    <- xmlRoot(doc.parsed)
> doc.body    <- xmlChildren(doc.root)$body
>
> doc.nodes   <- getNodeSet(doc.body, "//a[@href]")
> sapply(doc.nodes, function(el) removeAttributes(el))
>
> [[1]]
> <a>Some link text</a> 
>
> [[2]]
> <a>Africa</a> 
>
> [[3]]
> <a>Arabic</a> 
>
> [[4]]
> <a>Argentina</a>
> ```
>
> *** Q. Any thoughts on how to apply these updated nodes back into the
>   original html file?***

Comment: Do you need to to this in R? Can you use something like XSLT instead? If the HTML is well-formed XML or can be tidied up, it would be simple.

Comment: Ideally yeah.  Trying to build a rather large workflow in R as part of my PhD.  If you have a non-R solution do post it, if I can translate it to R I will but it still might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have a non-R solution do post it, if I can translate it to R I will but it still might be useful for others.

Assuming that the HTML is either well-formed in the first place or can be tidied up, you could use a very simple XSLT stylesheet to transform the document.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="a/@href"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

To my knowledge, you can apply XSLT transformations with R, it's just a matter of finding a package that can. How about the [Sxslt package](http://www.omegahat.org/Sxslt/)? Perhaps you will find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27966086/1987598) useful.